# How to add multiple columns generated from other columns - numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let's start with simple example: I have array with three columns A,B,C. I want to add additional columns to array:

- A/B
- A/C
- B/C

Those new columns are generated from old ones by simple element-wise division, all possible combinations except symmetric (e.g. B/A) are included. It is easy to do manually for small number of initial columns, but if I have e.g 20 starting columns then 20*(20-1)/2 = 190 new columns...

How to do it in smart way?

The second part is how to use user-defined function instead of division e.g. A+B-A*B

Any help you can provide would be great.

Comment: The second problem : `mean(A,B)[i]..` isn't clear to me. Could you clarify on `i` there or add a working code that works for a smaller dataset?

Comment: I was thinking about something like, this:
def myDiv(x,y):
    return x/y

arr = np.random.ranf((5,4)) 

r,c = np.triu_indices(arr.shape[1],1)
#arr[:,r]/arr[:,c] #new ratios
newArr=myDiv(arr[:,r],arr[:,c])

Comment: Please add to the question. It's hard to read from comments.

Comment: [i] was misleading. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the division problem, we could have a generic solution upon generating the pairwise combinations of those column numbers using [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html), like so-

```
from __future__ import division

r,c = np.triu_indices(arr.shape[1],1) # pairwise column IDs
out = arr[:,r]/arr[:,c]
```

**Sample runs**

1) 3 columns (verify output values) :

```
In [74]: arr = np.random.randint(11,99,(5,3)) #Sample input array with 3 cols

In [75]: r,c = np.triu_indices(arr.shape[1],1)

In [76]: arr[:,r]/arr[:,c]
Out[76]: 
array([[ 1.85714286,  0.4875    ,  0.2625    ],
       [ 0.94565217,  0.92553191,  0.9787234 ],
       [ 0.45652174,  0.24137931,  0.52873563],
       [ 0.84931507,  0.69662921,  0.82022472],
       [ 0.23170732,  0.52777778,  2.27777778]])

In [77]: arr[:,0]/arr[:,1]
Out[77]: array([ 1.85714286,  0.94565217,  0.45652174,  0.84931507,  0.23170732])

In [78]: arr[:,0]/arr[:,2]
Out[78]: array([ 0.4875    ,  0.92553191,  0.24137931,  0.69662921,  0.52777778])

In [79]: arr[:,1]/arr[:,2]
Out[79]: array([ 0.2625    ,  0.9787234 ,  0.52873563,  0.82022472,  2.27777778])
```

2) 20 columns (verify output ) :

```
In [71]: arr = np.random.randint(11,99,(5,20)) #Sample input array with 20 cols

In [72]: r,c = np.triu_indices(arr.shape[1],1)

In [73]: (arr[:,r]/arr[:,c]).shape # Verify output array shape
Out[73]: (5, 190)
```